# Solving a recurrence relation using Divide and Conquer Master Theorem

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

For the recurrence relation

$$T(n) = 16T(n/4) + n!\,,$$

I have found that $T(n)\in Θ(n!)$.
Can this be deduced using the Master Theorem?

Comment: Yes, it is the 3$^th$ case of the MT.
Problem 10: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS433-CS9624/Resources/master.pdf

Comment: Note that "time complexity" (which I edited out of the title) does not make an appearence here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Recall that the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) deals with recurrences of the form
$$
T(n) = a\cdot T\left(\frac{n}{b}\right)+f(n)
$$
In your particular case you have $a = 16$, $b=4$ and $f(n) = n!$.

Then we decide the complexity by comparing $f(n)$ to three functions of $n$, $a$ and $b$ (really we compare it basically the same function, with a $\log$ wiggle room, but in different ways).

In particular the third case holds where $f(n) \in \Omega(n^{c})$ where $c > \log_{b}a$. You have that $\log_{b}a = \log_{4}16 = 2$, so you have to prove (or at least convince yourself, depending on how rigorous you're being) that $n! \in \Omega(n^{c})$ for some $c > 2$.

It should be reasonably clear that you can pick any constant $c$ in this instance, and that this case holds. As it does, we get immediately (which is of course the point of the Master Theorem) that $T(n) \in \Theta(f(n))$, which in this case gives $T(n) \in \Theta(n!)$.

Comment: Do you think that this example is worth particular mention? If so, you might want to add it to the [Master theorem answer of our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers).